# Multiple timers at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, import, timer

EDIT: i now get a runtimeerror: 'main thread is not in mainloop' when the second timer reaches 0 and calls the Note() function

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer
from tkinter import messagebox
import json


def Note():
    z = messagebox.showinfo("Note", note)

class Timers:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c,d,e):
        self.a = month
        self.b = day
        self.c = hour
        self.d = minute
        self.e = note
        x = datetime.today()
        y = x.replace(month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=minute, second=0, microsecond=0)
        delta_t = y - x
        secs = delta_t.seconds


        T = Timer(secs, Note)
        T.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would want to use json to store a list of data objects

```
def save_some_object(a,b,c):
    with open("some_file.txt","wb") as f:
         json.dump({'a':a,'b':b},f)
```

in your case the object you  want to save is a **LIST** of datetime metadata

alarms_list = [{'hour':5,'minute':5,'second':0,'day':1,'month':1,'year':2019},
             {'hour':6,'minute':5,'second':0,'day':1,'month':1,'year':2021}]

and then you can save them to your file

```
with open("some_file.txt","wb") as f:
     json.dump(alarms_list,f)
```

you can load your list of alarms also with json

```
with open("some_file.txt","rb") as f:
     my_alarm_data_list = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Thank you, i have come further but have an issue still. When the second timer gets to 0 i get the error: "main thread is not in main loop".  i updated my question with my new code so maybe you could help me a bit more. thanks in advance.